# How do I convert clojure.lang.ArraySeq to a Java String[]?

Tags: clojure

I have a Java class with a constructor taking a variable number of String arguments like this:

```
public Foo(String...args);
```

I'm trying to create a make-foo multimethod in Clojure to handle this:

```
(defmethod make-foo clojure.lang.ArraySeq [& args] (new Foo (into-array args)))
```

But when I call it with

```
(make-foo ["one" "two"])
```

I get: IllegalArgumentException No matching ctor found

I'd also like to be able to call it with

```
(make-foo '("one" "two"))
```

I see there are to-array variants for ints, floats, etc, but no String. So how do I handle this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make-foo` as written would work if you called it like `(make-foo "one" "two")`, or you could remove the `&` from its definition and then pass it sequences.

Comment: Removing the & did the trick. I didn't realize all the defmethod forms didn't have to have the same argument signature